# Error handling: How to throw/catch errors correctly

Tags: ruby

I have a method that calls two other methods:

```
def first_method
  second_method

  # Don´t call this method when something went wrong before
  third_method
end
```

The second_method calls other methods:

```
def second_method
  fourth_method
  fifth_method
end
```

Let´s say the fifth_method has a begin/rescue statement:

```
def fifth_method
  begin
    # do_something
  rescue Error => e
    # 
  end
end
```

Now I want to avoid third_method to be called when fifth_method throws an error. How would I/you solve this most elegantly in Ruby.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me so obvious but anyway

```
def first_method
  begin 
    second_method
  rescue
    return
  end
  third_method
end
```

This construction (without explicit type of exception) will catch `StandartError` exception.

To avoid intersection with another exceptions you can create your own exception class:

```
class MyError < StandardError; end
```

and then use it

```
begin 
  second_method
rescue MyError => e
  return
end
```

Note that you should not inherit exception from `Exception` because this type of exceptions are from environment level, where the exceptions of `StandardError` are meant to deal with application level errors.

Comment: I don't understand, maybe you should read the tutorial about ruby exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way is removing error catching from fifth_method and move it to the first_method

```
def first_method
  begin 
     second_method

     third_method
  rescue Error => e

  end
end


def fifth_method
   # do_something

end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use exceptions, you can just return a status:

```
def fifth_method
  # do_something
  true
rescue Error => e
  false
end

def first_method
  if second_method
    third_method
  end
end
```